# How to verify if a text exist duplicate in page using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a test case to check if a system accpete creating an account by doubling
in the criteria for success I have to check if the account exists by doubling

is there a way to check that?

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot or link of wepage or html code

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example with `linkText`.
your element selector can be `By.linkText` if you can detect your element with `linkText` else you should change it with exact match of your element.
You can do this with following code :

```
int countOfElements = 0;
countOfElements = driver.findElements(By.linkText("textOfYourElement")).size();

Assert.assertEquals(1 , countOfElements); //if counts of your web element is equals to 1 then your test will pass.
```